# How can I smooth mathplotlib line

Tags: python, pandas

I have massive like ['2017-03-01':20,'2017-03-02':1,'2017-03-03':50] etc...

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

p = pd.Series(data=matr, index=matr.keys())
p.plot(x='Date', y='Value', rot=0, figsize=(14, 10), grid=True, marker='o')
plt.show()
```

My plot is very ugly
[image: result]

How can I make some smooth?

UPD I want a trend instead of broken data.

Comment: Define what you mean by smooth. The data above describes your data. Do you want to filter it? What kind of filter? Why kind of noise do you expect to see in the data? Are you looking for a trend line? On what size? All these questions are questions you need to answer before making the line smooth. Otherwise, if all you want is smooth, a constant zero line is very smooth.

Comment: Yes, I want a trend instead of broken data.

Comment: You might want to try the rolling_mean (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) in that case. It would take the average of window consecutive points for plotting

Comment: @NCNecros, You have a lot of data points, I think even you finally get the trend line, it will look similar like the current plot, as long as you largely extend the x-axis to see the difference. One of my suggestions is that can your data be fitted by FFT(Fast Fourier Transform)? Because your data kindly like the signal with a very strong noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dov said, the problem is far from being uniquely determined, it depends on many parameters like "how much" you want to smooth it (the more smoothing the further away from original data), "how" you want to smooth it (looking only at the past, or also at the future; if you want to use constant weights, Gaussian weights, exponential, etc.), etc.

Since you have a time series, I'm assuming you only want to look at the past, to avoid forecasting the future (data leaking).

The easiest solution is [rolling mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), as also David L said already:

```
p = p.rolling(5).mean()
```

This gives you on each day the average of the 5 previous days, which is clearly smoother (if you use larger numbers you get smoother lines).

This has the drawback that data from 5 days earlier weighs as much as "fresh" data, while from 6 days back the weight is suddenly 0. A better result is obtained by [exponential moving average](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ewm.html):

```
p = p.ewm(com=5).mean()
```

This gives a similar result to the above, but the weights are decreasing in an exponential way in order to give almost full weight to the previous day, a bit less the one before, then still a bit less, etc. (5 here is the "center of mass", for practical purposes you should roughly use the same parameter as in the first line to get similar results)